# Android SQLite Syntax for max value in a field

Tags: android, sqlite

Trying to get the maximum value in a column via an SQLite query. From everything that I am reading my code should work. But it doesn't. Here is the code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = myDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(GAME_COLUMN) FROM GAMES_TABLE", null);
```

The table is empty at this point, not that I think it should matter. Here is the error:

> sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "null": syntax error

I must be writing this incorrectly, but I don't see the mistake. The table and column names are entered corectly. Can anybody spot this?

Apologies in advance if I'm overlooking something stupid. Pretty new to SQLite.

Thanks!

Comment: table name is `GAME_COLUMN`?

Comment: Something tells me that I am misunderstanding the syntax. There is a column (GAME_COLUMN) in a table (GAMES_TABLE). I'm trying to retrieve the largest value in that column. I thought that I put the column name right after MAX. No???

Comment: I changed the string to make the word 'MAX' be 'max' and that seems to have solved the problem. Apparently this was case sensitive??

Comment: strange! but I guess these are not case sensitive

Comment: It is assuming that I am correct that this is case sensitive. That just seems a little fishy to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `GAMES_TABLE` & `GAME_COLUMN` is variable of String type.

if those are variable then you have to write query like

`"SELECT MAX("+GAME_COLUMN+") FROM "+GAMES_TABLE`

It is better to use query instead of rawQuery like below

```
db.query(GAMES_TABLE, new String [] {"MAX("+GAME_COLUMN+")"}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thank you! I went this this approach instead.